# How to cancel HTTP upload from data events?

Tags: node.js

Given this simple webserver code:

```
console.log('starting');
var server = require('http').createServer();

server.on('connection',function(socket){console.log('*server/connection');});
server.on(
    'request',
    function(request, response){
        console.log('*server/request');
        request.on(
            'data',
            function(chunk){
                console.log('*request/data');
                // <!> How do I abort next data calls from here?
            }
        );
        request.on(
            'readable',
            function(chunk){
                console.log('*request/readable');
                // <!> How do I abort next readable calls from here?
            }
        );
        request.on(
            'end',
            function(){
                console.log('*request/end');
                response.writeHead(200,"OK");
                response.write('Hello');
                response.end();
            }
        );
        request.on('close',function(){ console.log('*request/close'); } );
        request.on('error',function(){ console.log('*request/error'); } );
    }
);
server.on('close',function(){console.log('server/close');});
server.on('checkContinue',function(request, response){console.log('*server/checkContinue');});
server.on('connect',function(request, socket, head){console.log('*server/connect');});
server.on('upgrade',function(request, socket, head){console.log('*server/upgrade');});
server.on('clientError',function(exception, socket){console.log('*server/clientError');});

server.listen(8080);
console.log('started');
```

When a POST or FILE is submited, my on data function is triggered one or more or several times. Sometimes (like an monstrous big file is sent) **I want to cancel this on data events and trigger the on end function to user** (later on I will display a "your post/file is too big"). How do I do it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The proper, spec-compliant thing to do here is simply send a HTTP [413](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.14) response early – that is, as soon as you detect that the client has sent more bytes than you want to handle.  It is up to you whether or not you terminate the socket after sending the error response.  This is in line with RFC 2616: (emphasis added)

> ### 413 Request Entity Too Large
>
> The server is refusing to process a request because the request entity is larger than the server is willing or able to process. **The server MAY close the connection to prevent the client from continuing the request.**

What happens next is not ideal.

- If you leave the socket open, all browsers (Chrome 30, IE 10, Firefox 21) will keep sending data until the entire file is uploaded.  Then and only then, the browser will display your error message.  This really sucks since the user must wait for the entire file to complete the upload, only to find out the server rejected it.  It also wastes your bandwidth.

  The browsers' current behavior is in violation of RFC 2616 § [8.2.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.2):

  > An HTTP/1.1 (or later) client sending a message-body SHOULD monitor the network connection for an error status while it is transmitting the request. If the client sees an error status, it SHOULD immediately cease transmitting the body. If the body is being sent using a "chunked" encoding (section 3.6), a zero length chunk and empty trailer MAY be used to prematurely mark the end of the message. If the body was preceded by a Content-Length header, the client MUST close the connection.

  There are [open Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174906) and [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=839078) issues, but don't expect a fix any time soon.
- If you close the socket immediately after sending the HTTP 413 response, all browsers will obviously stop uploading immediately, but <s>they</s> *most* currently show a "connection reset" error (or similar), not any HTML you might send in the response.

  Again, this is probably a violation of the spec (which allows the server to send a response early and close the connection), but I wouldn't expect browser fixes any time soon here either.

  **Update:** As of 4/15, Chrome *may* display your 413 HTML when you close the connection early.  This only works when the browser is running on Linux and Mac OS X.  On Windows, Chrome still displays `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` network error rather than the HTML you sent.  (IE 11 and Firefox 37 continue to just show a network error on all platforms.)

So your choices with traditional plain HTTP uploads are:

- Show a friendly error message, but only after the upload runs to completion.  This wastes time and bandwidth.
- Fail fast, but leave users confused with a cryptic browser error screen.

Your best bet here is probably to use a AJAX uploader where you have more control over the user experience.  You should still provide a tradtional upload form as a fallback, and I'd use the "fail fast" option (close the socket) to prevent wasted time and bandwidth.

Here's some example code that kills a request if it receives more than 1 kB.  I'm using Express, but the same should apply with node's vanilla HTTP library.

**Note:** In reality, you should use <s>[formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable)</s> [multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty) to process your uploads (it's what Connect/Express uses), and it has its [own way](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty#api) to monitor upload data.

```
var express = require("express")
    , app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Uploads &gt; 1 kB rejected<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="file"><input type="submit"></form>');
});

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    var size = 0;

    var gotData = function(d) {
        size += d.length; // add this chunk's size to the total number of bytes received thus far
        console.log('upload chunk', size);
        if (size > 1024) {
            console.log('aborting request');
            req.removeListener('data', gotData); // we need to remove the event listeners so that we don't end up here more than once
            req.removeListener('end', reqEnd);
            res.header('Connection', 'close'); // with the Connection: close header set, node will automatically close the socket...
            res.send(413, 'Upload too large'); // ... after sending a response
        }
    };

    var reqEnd = function() {
       res.send('ok, got ' + size + ' bytes');
    }

    req.on('data', gotData);

    req.on('end', reqEnd);
});

app.listen(3003);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, my master. Could not expect a better response. I've faced most problems you mentioned, like the connection reset cryptic error message; just thought could have a "correct" solution (and you confirmed it is a browser issue, not Node's). Seems the best workaround is use AJAX upload. Just for the record, I am using the vanilla NodeJS, I expect to learn the basics of the language before I go to a framework.

Comment: For the benefit of future onlookers, express/connect appear to be using multiparty now. Also, it is necessary to add a header in order to do a early disconnect, because connections from browsers usually use keep-alive connections. 

    res.header('Connection', 'close'); 
    res.send(413, 'Uploading too much!');

Comment: Thanks a lot. I encountered a similar problem last week. I was implementing a HTTP API that allow admins to upgrade the server.  The request contains the upgrade package, and the admin password. The server will make sure the package has the right format. I decided to let the server to stop receiving data and send 400 BAD REQUEST when it finds out the format is incorrect. The API works perfectly in Postman, but when I call it in Chrome and FF, I keep getting CONNECTION_ABORT/CONNECTION_RESET error. I got stuck for almost a week and it drove me crazy.

Comment: Great explanation and links. Still in 2023 the FF bug is open and the Chrome bug is archived. I came here too researching the network reset in the browser instead of the HTTP status code send early during the upload with XHR. In my case the server sends an early 409 and closes the connection to be sure for the browser to bugger off. Somewhat strange this has no solution still in 2023. Are we looking in the wrong places? (BTW: using XHR to have upload progress reporting.)

Answer (score 2):

The request parameter is an [http.IncomingMessage](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage) class which does not allow to stop the stream.

But you have access to the underlying [socket](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket), and you can abort it:

```
request.socket.end('too big !');
```

But I'm not sure that the browser will enjoy it... He will probably complain and indicates that connection was impropertly closed.

Comment: Yes, it end connections showing "The connection was reset" in the browser. I've seen solutions like these before. I need a prettier solution. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
var maxSize = 30 * 1024 * 1024;    //30MB
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {

    var size = req.headers['content-length'];
    if (size <= maxSize) {
        form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
            console.log("File uploading");
            if (files && files.upload) {
                res.status(200).json({fields: fields, files: files});
                fs.renameSync(files.upload[0].path, uploadDir + files.upload[0].originalFilename);
            }
            else {
              res.send("Not uploading");
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        res.send(413, "File to large");
    }
```

And in case of wasting client's uploading time before get response, control it in the client javascript.

```
if (fileElement.files[0].size > maxSize) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Formidable this way:

```js
var formidable = require('formidable'),
    http = require('http'),
    util = require('util');

var MaxFieldSize = 1000 * 1000,
    MaxFields = 100,
    MaxUploadSize = 8 * 1000 * 1000;


http.createServer (function(req, res) {

    console.log (req.url);
    console.log (req.headers ["content-type"]);

    if (req.url == '/upload')
    {
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

        form.maxFieldsSize = MaxFieldSize;
        form.maxFields = MaxFields;

        form.on ('progress', function (bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
            //console.log (bytesReceived, bytesExpected);
            if (bytesReceived > MaxUploadSize)
            {
                console.log ('*** TOO BIG');

                // ***HACK*** see Formidable lib/incoming_form.js
                // forces close files then triggers error in form.parse below
                // bonus: removes temporary files
                // --> use throttling in Chrome while opening /tmp in nautilus
                //     and watch the files disappear
                form.__2big__ = true;
                form._error (new Error ('too big'));

                //req.connection.destroy (); --- moved to form.parse
            }
        });

        form.parse (req, function (err, fields, files) {
            if (err)
            {
                console.log ('*** A', err);
                try // just in case something is wrong with the connection, e.g. closed
                {
                    // might not get through?
                    if (form.__2big__)
                    {
                        res.writeHead (413, {"connection": 'close', "content-type": 'text/plain'});
                        res.end ('upload to big');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        res.writeHead (500, {"connection": 'close', "content-type": 'text/plain'});
                        res.end ('something wrong');
                    }
                    req.connection.destroy ();
                }
                catch (err)
                {
                    console.log ('*** B', err);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                res.writeHead (200, {"content-type": 'text/plain'});
                res.write ('received upload:\n\n');
                //for (let f in files)
                //    console.log (f, files [f]);
                res.end (util.inspect ({fields: fields, files: files}));
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        res.writeHead (200, {"content-type": 'text/html'});
        res.end (
            '<html>\
                <head>\
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">\
                    <title>Test Formidable</title>\
                </head>\
                <body>\
                    <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">\
                        <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="1">\
                        <input type="text" name="fooh" value="2"><br>\
                        <input type="file" name="bar"><br>\
                        <input type="file" name="baz"><br>\
                        <input type="file" name="boo"><br>\
                        <button type="submit">Submit</submit>\
                    </form>\
                </body>\
            </html>'
        );
    }
}).listen(8080);


/* terminal:
    #> node upload
    /upload
    multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryvqt1lXRmxeHLZtYi
    *** TOO BIG
    *** A Error: too big
        at IncomingForm.<anonymous> (/home/marc/Project/node/upload.js:33:18)
        at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
        at IncomingForm.emit (events.js:191:7)
        at IncomingForm.write (/home/marc/Project/node/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:155:8)
        at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/marc/Project/node/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:123:12)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
        at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:188:7)
        at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:387:10)
        at flow (_stream_readable.js:764:26)
        at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:744:3)
*/
```