# How to upload and parse large csv files in nodejs/express?

Tags: node.js, parsing, csv, express

I have nodejs/express application that should receive cvs files parse them and store parsed values into mongodb database.

How should I make upload route for that files in express? Should I use streams?

Comment: This answer should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18370751/171456

Comment: Thanks for the reply but how can I parse every chunk?

Answer (score 3):

[fast-csv](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv) and [csv-stream](https://github.com/lbdremy/node-csv-stream) both provide you with a stream that you can pipe data into and get records as they are parsed.

Comment: how to upload from browser ? base 64 or any other method