# NodeJs Simple upload file dont return correct result

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code below is my Node.js upload file. This code works fine and can upload any file from client, but after upload, I can't get upload status result. For example on Node.js, after upload file, I can't send uploading result to client.

```
var socket = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = socket.listen(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var mysql = require('mysql');
var multer = require('multer');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'a',
    database: 'signal'
});

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './uploads');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, req.params.storeId);
    }
});
var upload = multer({storage: storage}).single('userPhoto');

app.post('/newVitrine/:storeId/:userId', function (req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({'result': 0});
            console.log({'result': 0});
        } else {
            res.send({'result': 1});
            console.log({'result': 1});
        }
    });
});

server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});
```

Client should get json object as `{'result': 1}` but instead I get long json object and `result` isn't in to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Tere is nothing you can do. You can use ajax and fake it; make it look like it is working as expected.Even file uploading services does that - such as transloadit.

The problem is a very general problem actually, if multer hits a size limit exceed, that happens(though my situation was a little bit different), it aborts the connection and that causes the problem; you can not send response to the client on aborted connection.

Check this perfect answer which explains  a lot :

[How to cancel HTTP upload from data events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367824/how-to-cancel-http-upload-from-data-events/18370751#18370751)

Here is the working example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

var multer = require('multer');


var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './temp')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
});
var upload = multer({storage: storage}).single('upload');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    res.send(`<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upld" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="title"><br>
        <input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="upldbtn">
        </form>        
        `
    );
});


app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({'result': 0});
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.send({'result': "custom result"});
            console.log({'result': 1});
        }
    });
});

server.listen("9090", function () {
    console.log('Server listening at port');
});
```

Comment: I'm read the article, but that doesnt my problem and i want to send simple json to client as Android devices

Comment: Because before your route executes, the response is already sent. You are trying to send second response. You should use the success event.

Comment: I have updated my answer with working code, the problem of yours was probably the upload field name, you expected "userPhoto" but didn't provide us the form, so i can not say exactly. I changed it to "upload" and updated the code and it worked.

Comment: Thanks sir. please let me to test that

Comment: you said to me `Because before your route executes, the response is already sent`. which line is your means?

Comment: I am sorry Mahdi, that was not your case, you can ignore it. At first glance i thought that was the issue since you didn't share your all code(form) I just guessed wrong because it was looking okay over all...:)

Comment: @Mahdi If did help you my answer, could you approve?

Comment: Oh!! i'm sorry sir. i had forgotten to accept that, yes no problem

Comment: could you help me other problem on `nodeJs` ?