# ASP.NET - Cannot get error response immediately when uploading very large file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman

When I use Postman to try uploading a large file to my server (written in .NET Core 2.2), Postman immediately shows the `HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found` error: `The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length`

But when I use my code to upload that large file, it gets stuck at the line to send the file.

My client code:

```
    public async void TestUpload() {
        StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead("D:/Desktop/large.zip"));
        streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"large.zip\"");
        MultipartFormDataContent multipartFormDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        multipartFormDataContent.Add(streamContent);
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://localhost:44334/api/user/testupload");
        try {
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, multipartFormDataContent);
            bool success = httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
```

My server code:

```
    [HttpPost, Route("testupload")]
    public async Task UploadFile(IFormFileCollection formFileCollection) {
        IFormFileCollection formFiles = Request.Form.Files;
        foreach (var item in formFiles) {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine("D:/Desktop/a", item.FileName), FileMode.Create)) {
                await item.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }
    }
```

My client code gets stuck at the line `HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, multipartFormDataContent)`, while the server doesn't receive any request (I use a breakpoint to ensure that).

It gets stuck longer if the file is bigger. Looking at Task Manager, I can see my client program uses up high CPU and Disk as it is actually uploading the file to the server. After a while, the code moves to the next line which is

```
bool success = httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode
```

Then by reading the response content, I get exactly the result as of Postman.

Now I want to know how to immediately get the error to be able to notify the user in time, I don't want to wait really long.

Note that when I use Postman to upload large files, my server doesn't receive any request as well. I think I am missing something, maybe there is problem with my client code.

EDIT: Actually I think it is the client-side error. But if it is server-side error, then it still doesn't mean too much for me. Because, let me clear my thought. I want to create this little helper class that I can use across projects, maybe I can share it with my friends too. So I think it should be able, like Postman, to determine the error as soon as possible. If Postman can do, I can too.

EDIT2: It's weird that today I found out Postman does NOT know before hand whether the server accepts big requests, I uploaded a big file and I saw it actually sent the whole file to the server until it got the response. Now I don't believe in myself anymore, why I thought Postman knows ahead of time the error, I must be stupid. But it does mean that I have found a way to do my job even better than Postman, so I think this question might be useful for someone.

Comment: I suspect postman is using http 1.1 which is chunk mode and your c# is using http 1.0 which is stream mode.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the postman request with the c# request to see differences.

Comment: Your server will be receiving the request you send from Postman, it is just not reaching your code as it's rejected earlier in the pipeline. You will need to change some configuration to allow the big request.

Comment: @dezfowler I know how to allow big requests. But I meant I want my code acts just like Postman, I wouldn't make any changes to my server because it's not the cause.

Comment: Incorrect. Your server *is* the cause. The client sends the request and then waits for the server to respond. At some point, the request will eventually time out, but until that happens, it's 100% on the server to abort and send an error response. Otherwise, the client is just going to wait until the timeout threshold.

Comment: @peanut I didn't mean your server is the cause of this problem, just that if you want to see the request come through you need to change some stuff on the server side. I think this is probably  because you aren't setting the Content-Length header on the stream content. You should get the file length from the file system and set the header. Otherwise the StreamContent is probably reading the entire file in order to determine the length first. It doesn't know the source of the stream and that it's able to get the length a different way.

Comment: I faced with same problem and I found it, I hope it can help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367824/how-to-cancel-http-upload-from-data-events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am able to do what I wanted. But first I want to thank you @Marko Papic, your informations do help me in thinking about a way to do what I want.

What I am doing is:

1. First, create an empty `ByteArrayContent` request, with the `ContentLength` of the file I want to upload to the server.
2. Second, surround `HttpResponseMessage = await HttpClient.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage)` in a `try-catch` block. The `catch` block catches `HttpRequestException` because I am sending a request with the length of the file but my actual content length is 0, so it will throw an `HttpRequestException` with the message `Cannot close stream until all bytes are written`.
3. If the code reaches the `catch` block, it means the server **ALLOWS** requests with the file size or bigger. If there is no exception and the code moves on to the next line, then if `HttpResponseMessage.StatusCode` is **404**, it means the server **DENIES** requests bigger than the file size. The case when `HttpResponseMessage.StatusCode` is **NOT 404** will never happen (I'm not sure about this one though).

My final code up to this point:

```
    private async Task<bool> IsBigRequestAllowed() {
        FileStream fileStream = File.Open("D:/Desktop/big.zip", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        if(fileStream.Length == 0) {
            fileStream.Close();
            return true;
        }
        HttpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
        HttpMethod = HttpMethod.Post;
        HttpRequestMessage.Method = HttpMethod;
        HttpRequestMessage.RequestUri = new Uri("https://localhost:55555/api/user/testupload");
        HttpRequestMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(new byte[] { });
        HttpRequestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength = fileStream.Length;
        fileStream.Close();
        try {
            HttpResponseMessage = await HttpClient.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage);
            if (HttpResponseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound) {
                return false;
            }
            return true; // The code will never reach this line though
        }
        catch(HttpRequestException) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:** Note that my approach still has a problem. The problem with my code is the `ContentLength` property, it shouldn't be exact the length of the file, it should be bigger. For example, if my file is exactly 1000 bytes in length, then if the file is successfully uploaded to the server, the `Request` that the server gets has greater `ContentLength` value. Because `HttpClient` doesn't just only send the content of the file, but it has to send many informations in addition. It has to send the boundaries, content types, hyphens, line breaks, etc... Generally speaking, you should somehow find out before hand the exact bytes that `HttpClient` will send along with your files to make this approach work perfectly (I still don't know how so far, I'm running out of time. I will find out and update my answer later).

Now I am able to immediately determine ahead of time whether the server can accept requests that are as big as the file my user wants to upload.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue has nothing to do with your server-side C# code. Your request gets stuck because of what is happening between the client and the server (by "server" I mean IIS, Apache, Nginx..., not your server-side code).

**In HTTP, most clients don't read response until they send all the request data.** So, even if your server discovers that the request is too large and returns an error response, the client will not read that response until the server accepts the whole requests.

When it comes to server-side, you can check [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/360479/why-might-a-413-not-be-flushed-to-the-client-immediately), but I think **it would be more convenient to handle it on the client side**, by checking the file size before sending it to the server (this is basically what Postman is doing in your case).