# Can I send HTTP response before completely read HTTP request?

Tags: http, tcp, w3c

Can I send HTTP response before completely read HTTP request?

For example if user POST large file - exceed size limit or service send wrong header and we don't need to process rest of data and replay with HTTP error code?

**UPDATE** I finally found that this question had been already asked:

- [Is it acceptable for a server to send a HTTP response before the entire request has been received?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250991/is-it-acceptable-for-a-server-to-send-a-http-response-before-the-entire-request)
- [How to cancel HTTP upload from data events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367824/how-to-cancel-http-upload-from-data-events)

and it is possible but browser implementation are "broken" - doesn't take into account such event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying from the [@David Hodgson's answer from the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14483857/1026) here, so that this doesn't look unanswered:

Yes, a server is allowed to do that by the specification.

No, clients don't handle it properly.