# Can a web server begin responding before the client has sent the full request?

Tags: http

I am writing a web application for an academic research group. The researchers need to be able to upload large data sets (100MB - 1GB) in CSV format. I've written the server to process the data as it comes in. This means that if there is an error in the first row of the CSV, we can return an error straight away.

However, when this happens, the browser reports that "The connection was reset" or similar. Clearly, my web server is responding in a way that doesn't make sense.

If I explicitly close the HTTP request stream (this is Kotlin on the JVM by the way) before returning the error to the browser, then the problem goes away. However, it turns out that the close implementation of the request stream first goes and reads the whole stream to its end. So at that point the user still has to wait 30mins+ to find out that there is an error in the first row of their CSV.

Is what I am trying to do possible? Does the HTTP protocol permit a web server, in any circumstances, to begin responding before the full request body has been sent? If not, can you suggest a workaround that would allow me to deliver a user experience where the user doesn't have to wait for the whole file to be uploaded before finding out if there are any problems?

Comment: Upload in chunks (plenty of examples out there), then check each chunk for problems, error out.

Comment: You could use asynchronous requests and loop through the CSV sending one line at a time depending on what app you are using to send the file. If it is a browser you may be able to use HTML5 file API

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I feel like you are answering my question about a workaround. Does this mean that you think that the HTTP protocol does not allow what I'm doing, or you aren't sure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, according to the http spec servers should be able to send responses early and the client should stop sending the request body. Most browsers however, don't implement this correctly.

In theory, your http server needs to return a 4xx error code with a response body, then reset the connection to prevent the upload continuing in the background. See the answers below for a more detailed description of the issue. There are a couple of browser versions that do support this, so if you're doing this in lab conditions where you can control the client being used the links below will help.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14483857/2274303

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18370751/2274303

[edit]

To answer your question about using a workaround, chunking the uploads using javascript is a good way to mitigate internet connectivity issues, but if you want to parse it in real time it's not as simple as arbitrarily breaking up the file into pieces. You need to make sure you're not splitting the file in the middle of a line, otherwise it will fail even if the data is valid. That brings up the issue of parsing a 1GB file in javascript, which isn't a good idea imo.

If you want to use javascript, continue uploading the entire file at once via an ajax request, so you can get the response outside of the main dom and force a redirect or cancel the upload. Depending on which js libraries you're using there are different ways of doing this.

None of this solves the reverse scenario. What if the file is 95% uploaded before there's an error? The researcher will need to either upload the whole thing again or edit the file to only include the rows from the error going forward. That means your application needs to support partial uploads and know to pick up where it left off. All these things are possible, but you're probably not going to find a simple workaround to get this working well.

Without understanding the dataset and what kind of validation you are doing it's hard to come up with a full solution. If parsing each row doesn't depend on the previous rows being valid, you could always upload the whole file, then display the rows with errors at the end and ask them to upload a second file with just the corrections.

Answer (score 0):

The normal process of a HTTP web server happens like:

```
Server listens for request
Client creates request
Client sends request to server
Server processes request
Server creates response
Server sends response to client
Client processes response
```

The client starts the connection for communication and the server is able to respond on that connection, however if you close the connection the server will need to send a response on another connection. The browser may not allow the server to start a new connection that the client didn't request.

You may be able to respond by reading the first line and creating an error quickly, but the client will not read the response until it is done sending the request.

By sending the file in chunks or asynchronously sending lines of the file, you will be able to give feedback more immediately. You will be sending many smaller requests with the ability to respond in between.

The question was about HTTP protocol. I feel like this would be allowed by the protocol if you wrote a custom app and web app, however if you are using browsers then you must use HTTP as the companies have implemented it. In a custom app you could check for interruptions however most browsers will probably fire a full request before listening for a response, which is also a reason AJAX took off 20years ago.