# HTTP 1.1 is it allowed to send response while request it still streaming chunks?

Tags: http

Is it allowed by HTTP 1.1 to send a chunked response to the client while the client request is still streaming chunked data, or I must wait until the request is completed with chunk 0 and then start streaming the chunked response?

Comment: [Please don't add "thanks"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989). :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it acceptable for a server to send a HTTP response before the entire request has been received?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250991/is-it-acceptable-for-a-server-to-send-a-http-response-before-the-entire-request)

Comment: @maksadbek it is slightly different as request and response are chunked in m example