# Must HTTP web server accept full multi-part upload before responding 401 UNAUTHORIZED?

Tags: http, http-headers, multipartform-data, multipart

Is it possible for an HTTP web server to verify `Authorization` header contents of a `multi-part/form-data` file upload request before accepting the full uploaded file contents?

Can it at least verify `Authorization` header for each multipart request part of a multi-part file upload request and cancel upload at least at the multi-part boundary?

Comment: Tricky question, but my own opinion is that on Auth header failure you should send a 403 with connection:close, and close the socket, even if the client is still sending tons of bytes. But I don't remember seing the Authorization headers inside the multi-part boundaries. Isn't that header only set on the main request headers? Don't you have only mime type and size on boundaries headers?

Comment: Checked the AWS file upload (content type application/octet). It sends back 403 immediately, not waiting for full file upload.
Also, according to this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250991/is-it-acceptable-for-a-server-to-send-a-http-response-before-the-entire-request
HTTP protocol doesn't require wait for full upload before responding.