# Servlet response ignored when uploading large file to Apache FileUpload

Tags: tomcat, servlets, file-upload

I'm experiencing strange behaviour when using Apache FileUpload with filesize limit and Tomcat web application server (version 9). Here's my code:

```
  List<FileItem> multi = null;

  try {
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));

    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    upload.setFileSizeMax(2 * 1024 * 1024); // 2MB
    upload.setHeaderEncoding("UTF-8");
    multi = upload.parseRequest(request);

    ...
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  // send servlet response
  ...
```

As visible above, the file size limit is 2MB.

If I upload a 1MB file, everything is OK, my servlet response is sent to client.

If I upload a 3MB file, behaviour is OK: the exception is thrown and my servlet response is sent to client.

If I upload a 10MB file, behaviour is NOT OK. The exception is thrown but my servlet response is never sent to client. WireShark shows me that tomcat respond with RST message and then client tries to send the request again and again.

After long debug, I could see that I could bypass the reset code (RST) by setting the `maxSwallowSize` connector attribute (defined in `server.xml`) to -1, or to a value bigger that 10MB.

Everything is OK if I remove `setFileSizeMax()` call.

My questions are:

- Why is behaviour different on 3MB and 10MB files since they are both larger than 2BM limit ?
- What is role of `maxSwallowSize` when file is smaller/larger than limit

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since Servlet 3.0 (Tomcat 7.0), the functionality of `commons-fileupload` is integrated into servlet containers: see [`HttpServletRequest#getParts`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/http/httpservletrequest#getParts--). You should consider using this API instead. Under the hood most servlet containers (including Tomcat) use a repackaged version of `commons-fileupload`.

The `maxSwallowSize` attribute of a connector tells Tomcat how many more bytes can the HTTP client send **after** your already finished processing the request, before Tomcat resets the TCP socket. In your case this means how many more bytes over the 2 MiB limit can the browser send.

This is a security measure: the HTTP protocol itself **does** allow the server to send an error response **before** receiving the complete request (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14250991/11748454)), but some browser do not comply with this (and in your case you don't send an error status). Try adding:

```java
catch (SizeException e) {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE);
}
```

to your `catch` clauses. If your browser complies in a timely fashion to the error status code, it will stop uploading before the `maxSwallowSize` limit is reached and the client will display a `413` error page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It confirm my suspicions. I already tried to send a 413 status  without any change. As mentionned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18370751/1585114 it seems that client (chrome and firefox) ignore this stauts and continue sending data anyway.